# How to change the value of a specific item in a 2D array in a list in c#

Tags: c#, list

I tried to change the list item as of a list of a 2D array as follows, but I thinks it is a wrong way because my application become not responding when calling this code snippet:

```
public List<int[,]> Mutation(int[] RouletteWheel, List<int[,]> population)
{
    double rndNumber1 = 0.0;
    int chrom1 = 0;
    int rndNumber2 = 0;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < population.Count; i++) // For all Chromosomes
    {
        rndNumber1 = rnd.Next(0, 10) / 100; // generate a random number between 0 and 10 and divide result by 100
        chrom1 = RouletteWheel[rnd.Next(0, 9)];

        if (rndNumber1 <= Pm) /* check if we will do Crossover */
        {
            rndNumber2 = rnd.Next(0, rows - 1); // determine the crossover point randomly by generating number between 0 and rows -1 

            for (int j = 0; j < rows - 1; j++)
            {
                for (int v = 0; v < columns - 1; v++)
                {
                    if (j == rndNumber2) /* Mutate the cell that is equal to 1 */
                    {
                        if (population[chrom1][j, v] == 0)
                        {
                            population[chrom1][j, v] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return population;
}
```

I need to know why my app become not responding when calling this method?

Comment: what's `chrom1` here?

Comment: I've updated the code ...

Comment: Depending on the size of population and the values of rows and cols, executing this code can take a lot of time. What are typical values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't finished reviewing the entire code sample yet, but I did notice one thing. Take a look at this use of `Random()`:

```
rndNumber1 = rnd.Next(0, 10) / 100; // generate a random number between 0 and 10 and divide result by 100
if (rndNumber1 <= Pm) /* check if we will do Crossover */
{
    //...
}
```

There are several mistakes here that ultimately lead to unexpected results. The first is the upper bound for `rnd.Next()` is *exclusive*. This means the `rnd.Next()` call will produce results from `0` to `9`. It will never be a `10`, which is contrary to the comment next to that line. (This same mistake is made for the other uses of Random in this code as well).

The next thing to understand is we're working entirely with *integers* here. That includes doing integer division, which will discard any decimal portion of a result. So when we divide a number in the range 0 to 9 (or even 0 to 10) by 100, the result are **not** `.00` to `.09` or `.00` to `.10`. The result is **0**. It's not enough that `rndNumber1` is declared as a `double`. The integer result of the division expression is determined *before* the assignment to the double variable.

In other words, no matter what the `rnd.Next()` call returns, `rndNumber1` will **always** end up as **`0`**.

Now go check the next line, and I suspect 0 is always less then the `Pm` value. This means the code will run the (possibly) expensive computations in that `if()` block for **all** of the records in the populuation, when it seems like you really only wanted to do this for about 5% of the records. And that *might* explain why it's taking so long.

A further reading of the code also shows it checks every row in a chromosome for the random number match, when it could just reference that row directly. That fix will also help the code run much faster.

```
//No need to return anything. The population mutation will be seen by the caller.
//Additionally, the Roullette wheel was never used.
public void Mutation(IEnumerable<int[,]> population)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    foreach(int[,] chromosome in population)
    {
        double selectionFactor = rnd.Next(0, 11) / 100.0D; // generate a random number between 0 and 10 and divide result by 100
        //Pm could be passed to the method as an argument
        if (selectionFactor <= Pm) /* check if we will do Crossover */
        {
            int crossoverRow = rnd.Next(0, chromosome.GetLength(0)); 
            int columns = chromosome.GetLength(1);
            for(int c = 0; c < columns; c++)
            {
                if (chromosome[crossoverRow, c] == 0)
                {
                    chromosome[crossoverRow, c]  = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update:**

The code in the question has changed, and now makes even less sense than before. There is a loop for **every item in the population**:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < population.Count; i++)
```

But `i` is **never used** in that code. At least the `RouletteWheel` is used now, but only for restricting to *at most* the first 9 items of the populaution. That... can't be right. Not even close.

Answer (score 0):

Please see comments

```
public List<int[,]> Mutation(int[] RouletteWheel, List<int[,]> population)
{
    /* Note RouletteWheel is never used*/

    double rndNumber1 = 0.0;
    int chrom1 = 0;
    int rndNumber2 = 0;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    /* orig code had j< rows-1, but it should be j< rows or j<= rows-1*/
    for (int j = 0; j < rows ; j++) 
    {
        /* orig code had v < columns-1, but it should be 
           v < columns or v <= columns-1 */
        for (int v = 0; v < columns; v++)
        {
            /* Why is this if statement here? 
               rndNumber 2 is always 0, 
               you are only evaluating the first row */
            if (j == rndNumber2) /* Mutate the cell that is equal to 1 */
            {
                /* the following code will set all values that are 0 to 1*/
                if (population[chrom1][j, v] == 0)
                {
                    population[chrom1][j, v] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return population;
}
```